# PING w/ TIMESTAMP &

Tags: cmd, timestamp, ping

Using the standard windows CMD Prompt, I want to PING an IP "x" amount of times, and get results that are time stamped. The following does the job but it does not give PING STATISTICS at the end AND leave me ready for the next cmd.

```
ping -n 13  37.48.68.15|cmd /q /v /c "(pause&pause)>nul & for /l %a in () do (set /p "data=" && echo(!date! !time! !data!)&ping -n 2 37.48.68.15>nul"
```

I believe I am asking for 13 pings, but I only get 11, is there a resolve for that? AND Bonus Points if it will automatically print to a text file!

Photochop-EXAMPLE; http://www.plumbers.cc/images/tanki/cmd-example.jpg

Comment: Your two pauses chew 2 CRLF. Maybe that's it.

Comment: What is the goal? Please provide an example of the desired output.